# How can I change the creation order of views in a list?

Tags: sharepoint-views

This is a weird question that I will try to explain as best I can.  I have a list with many views.  I am using Kwiz-Com to control permissions on these views.  If an end-user clicks on an icon that is set to a view that they do not have permissions for, it automatically sends them to the first view that was ever created for this list.

So, if you are in the list settings, and you scroll down to Views; it does not keep them in alphabetical order but the order in which they were created.  Is it possible to change this order?  I would like to have a particular view be the view that end-users are directed to IF they do not have the permissions to look at the view that was linked to the icon they clicked on.

Hope this was confusing enough for you!!  Thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

The order is only a UI thingie

One View can be the default View, there is a CheckBox to set it when you edit that View

To get what you want you can redirect to another page by putting an Audience Tragetted CEWP on that default page with a documen.location JS redirect

Comment: I thought that the default view (which everyone has permissions to) would be the view you see if you don't have permissions to the view you clicked on.  But this is not the case, it actually sends the end-user to the first view that was created (which everyone also has permissions to).

I will try what you suggest to redirect them back to the default view.  Thank you!